# updating nested objects in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following issue I have a set of JSON rules like so

```
{
    "event": {
        "type": "maxrulecount",
        "params": {
            "maxrulecount": 2
        }
    },
    "conditions": {
        "any": [
            {
                "all": [
                    {
                        "fact": "apples",
                        "value": "20",
                        "operator": "greaterThanInclusive"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "all": [
                    {
                        "fact": "bananas",
                        "value": "100",
                        "operator": "greaterThanInclusive"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So i obviously convert this to an object but the number value remains a string so I have created a function that will convert any numbers that are strings into numbers like so

```
checkForNumberValues(rules) {
    // allows any number of numbers together or a decimal number
    let numberRegex = /^(([0-9]{1,})|([0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}))$/g;
    // yes a loop within a loop but time complexity is no issue here
    rules?.conditions?.any?.forEach((condition) => {
      condition?.all?.forEach((rule) => {
        console.log(rule.value, numberRegex.test(rule.value)); // this is working correctly
        if (numberRegex.test(rule.value)) {
          rule.value = Number(rule.value);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log(rules);
    return rules;
}
```

now i can see that it is correctly identifying numbers and setting the value but when i console the result like so

`console.log(checkForNumberValues(rules));`

I'ts returning the rules object with the string number values instead of the number values I set..

Do I need to do something special to set nested values??

Below is an example

```js
let rules = {
  conditions: {
    any: [
      {
        all: [
          { fact: 'orange', value: '70' },
          { fact: 'apple', value: '10' },
          { fact: 'brocolli', value: '54' },
          { fact: 'kiwi fruit', value: '199' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

function checkForNumberValues(rules) {
  let numberRegex = /^(([0-9]{1,})|([0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}))$/g;
  rules.conditions.any.forEach((condition) => {
    condition.all.forEach((rule) => {
      if (numberRegex.test(rule.value)) {
         rule.value = Number(rule.value);
      }
    })
  });
  return rules;
}

console.log(checkForNumberValues(rules));
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `rules` is an object and not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Comment: @Andreas they start off as JSON in my db and I convert it to the rules object regardless my question is, why isnt my object updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regexp` "remembers" the last index where a match was found when the global flag `g` is used (-> [Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results))

Use `parseInt()`/`Number()` and then test for `NaN`

```js
let rules = {
  conditions: {
    any: [
      {
        all: [
          { fact: 'orange', value: '70' },
          { fact: 'apple', value: '10' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

function checkForNumberValues(rules) {
  rules.conditions.any.forEach((condition) => {
    condition.all.forEach((rule) => {
      const val = parseInt(rule.value);
      
      if (!isNaN(val)) {
         rule.value = val;
      }
    })
  });
  return rules;
}

console.log(checkForNumberValues(rules));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isNaN` to check if the string is a number or not.

```js
let rules = {
  conditions: {
    any: [
      {
        all: [
          { fact: 'orange', value: '70' },
          { fact: 'apple', value: '10' },
          { fact: 'brocolli', value: '54' },
          { fact: 'kiwi fruit', value: '199' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

function checkForNumberValues(rules) {
  rules.conditions.any.forEach((condition) => {
    condition.all.forEach((rule) => {
      if (!isNaN(rule.value)) {
         rule.value = Number(rule.value);
      }
    })
  });
  return rules;
}

console.log(checkForNumberValues(rules));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try a different approach

```
let rules = {
        conditions: {
          any: [
            {
              all: [
                { fact: 'orange', value: '70' },
                { fact: 'apple', value: '10' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
rules.conditions.any.filter(x=>{(x.all).forEach(x=>x.value=parseInt(x.value))})
console.log(rules)
```